# using certbot-auto for nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

I have an nginx running.
Now I want my nginx to use SSL:

```
certbot-auto --nginx -d my.domain.com -n --agree-tos --email admin@mail.com
```

OUTPUT:

```
Performing the following challenges:
tls-sni-01 challenge for my.domain.com
Cleaning up challenges
Cannot find a VirtualHost matching domain my.domain.com.
```

my.domain.com is pointing to the IP of my server. It's its dns name. 
What am I doing wrong? I did this already for apache and it was working fine. My nginx is running (and I'm not able to restart it manually after the `certbot-auto` but this wasn't necessary when I used `certbot-auto --apache`

Comment: The error refers to your nginx config, not DNS/IP etc. There were [issues](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/3798) with the nginx config parsers that are due to be solved.

Comment: Can you post your nginx sites-enabled config?  should be located here if you're using Linux Ubuntu server -> /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my case, I had to add the "server_name" line because it wasn't in my nginx config so it was giving me the error message "Cannot find a VirtualHost matching domain my.domain.com" when I ran:

```
certbot --nginx
```

Make sure this is in your config:

```
server {
    server_name my.domain.com;
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your are probably missing some Server Blocks (virtual hosts) files in the sites-enabled folder. Check if your config files exist in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` **and** `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`. If they are not present in the sites-enabled folder, create symbolic links for them:

```
$ sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/my.domain.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

Add your site, check for config errors and restart nginx:

```
$ sudo certbot --nginx -d my.domain.com
$ sudo nginx -t
$ sudo service nginx restart
```